# iOS 10: UIImagePickerController type camera Status bar covers top content

Tags: uiimagepickercontroller, ios10

Using UIImagePickerController to capture the image, it is working fine on iOS9 but on iOS10 status bar covers the top content of controller.

[image: See the image bellow]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue in iOS 10.

It looks like Apple is hiding the status bar automatically when the UIImagePickerController is presented, but for that you must have UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance set with YES in your info.plist file.

If you must keep UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance with NO, you should hide the status bar by calling:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

And then set it back when UIImagePickerController is dismissed.